# Не могу организовать разбиение данных на группы Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Стоит передо мною такая задача:
[image]

Таблицы и данные такие:

```
create table t_lang (lang_id number , name varchar2(100));

delete t_lang;
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (1,'Chinese');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (2,'Spanish');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (4,'English');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (5,'Russian');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (6,'German');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (7,'French');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (8,'Italian');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (9,'Japanese');
insert into t_lang (lang_id,name) values (10,'Portuguese');
commit;


create table t_person (person_id number , name varchar2(100));
delete t_person;
insert into t_person (person_id,name) values (1,'Piter');
insert into t_person (person_id,name) values (2,'Anna');
insert into t_person (person_id,name) values (3,'Olga');
insert into t_person (person_id,name) values (4,'Max');
insert into t_person (person_id,name) values (5,'Ivan');
insert into t_person (person_id,name) values (6,'Sam');
insert into t_person (person_id,name) values (7,'Bill');
commit;



create table t_pers_lang (person_id number , lang_id number);
delete t_pers_lang;
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (1,4);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (1,5);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (2,6);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (2,7);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (3,9);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (3,6);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (4,4);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (4,7);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (5,1);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (6,10);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (6,8);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (7,2);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (7,8);
insert into t_pers_lang  (person_id,lang_id) values (7,1);
commit;
```

Написал такой запрос, который выводит нужный результат...

```
select
Группа,
listagg(f2, ', ') within group (order by f2) Участники,
listagg(f3, ', ') within group (order by f3) Языки
from
(
select
NTILE(2) OVER (ORDER BY pl.person_id) Группа,
(case when row_number() over (partition by p.person_id order by l.lang_id) = 1 then p.name end) f2,
(case when row_number() over (partition by l.lang_id order by p.person_id) = 1 then l.name end) f3
from t_lang l, t_person p, t_pers_lang pl 
where l.lang_id=pl.lang_id and p.person_id=pl.person_id
)
group by Группа;
```

... но есть одно НО!

Во вложенном запросе я использую NTILE(2), который просто навсего разбивает весь набор данных поровну, что является не правильным. Задача решена для частного случая.

Если поменять входные данные (например заменить ключ любого участника на другой), то запрос возвращает неверный результат.

Вопрос: как же мне всё таки разбить участников на группы, между которыми НЕвозможно общение?

Comment: Ваша задача мне чем-то напомнила [эту](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292792/get-a-number-of-unique-values-without-separating-values-that-belong-to-the-same) (осторожно, ОЧЕНЬ много английских букв). Я детали не помню уже, помню много общался с автором в скайпе. Насколько я помню, задача была идентичная - разбить множество на непересекающиеся группы.

Comment: Кажется, я даже знаю как сделать одним запросом (в тот раз не смог), но там можно мозг вывихнуть.

Comment: Пока кажется, что для решения этой задачи не обойтись без рекусии(`with`) или деревьев(`connect by`). С ними же задача решается довольно не сложно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось нечто монстрообразное и, подозреваю, прожорливое на больших исходных данных. Если кто может лучше, тоже буду благодарен:

```
with t (name, lang) as (
      select 'Piter', 'English' from dual union all
      select 'Piter', 'Russian' from dual union all
      select 'Anna',  'German' from dual union all
      select 'Anna',  'French' from dual union all
      select 'Olga',  'Japanese' from dual union all
      select 'Olga',  'German' from dual union all
      select 'Max',   'English' from dual union all
      select 'Max',   'French' from dual union all
      select 'Ivan',  'Chinese' from dual union all
      select 'Sam',   'Portuguese' from dual union all
      select 'Sam',   'Italian' from dual union all
      select 'Bill',  'Spanish' from dual union all
      select 'Bill',  'Italian' from dual union all
      select 'Bill',  'Chinese' from dual),
     s (name, lang, root_name) as (
        select name, lang, connect_by_root name root_name
                from t
             connect by nocycle (prior lang =  lang and prior name <> name)
                             or (prior lang <> lang and prior name =  name))
select distinct t1.names, t2.langs
  from (select root_name, listagg(name, ',') within group (order by name) names
          from (select distinct root_name, name
                  from s)
         group by root_name) t1 join
        (select root_name, listagg(lang, ',') within group (order by lang) langs
          from (select distinct root_name, lang
                  from s)
         group by root_name) t2 on t1.root_name = t2.root_name
```

Идея в том, что для каждого человека строится дерево (условие соединения - тот же язык, но другое имя, или то же имя, но другой язык), для дерева запоминаем корень, а потом для каждого корня делаем `list_agg` отдельно имен, и отдельно - языков. Фишка в том, что имена и языки сортируются, значит, списки будут совпадать для разных корней, если наборы одинаковые. А это значит, что они в одной группе. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил. Результат:

```
NAMES                 LANGS
------------------------------------------------------------
Anna,Max,Olga,Piter   English,French,German,Japanese,Russian
Bill,Ivan,Sam         Chinese,Italian,Portuguese,Spanish
```

Comment: На общую идею это не влияет, но в таком варианте у вас все сломается, если в таблице будут 2 человека с одинаковым именем. Все же соедниять надо по ID. Считаю это важным методическим моментом

Comment: А, ну да, само собой. Я просто объединил данные, чтобы с джойнами не заморачиваться и не усложнять исходные данные, которые в первый `with` завернуты.